# NSResponder print: call going to wrong place

Tags: cocoa, nsresponder

In my NSViewController I placed a print(_:) method, but it's not being called when I hit print.  Instead, the print is being captured by the current NSTextField that I'm in.  How do I force the print call to go into the view controller?  I defined it like so:

```swift
@objc func print(sender: AnyObject) { 
}
```

Comment: You can change the action and/or target of the menu item.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info please?  I'm brand new to Cocoa and the responder chain (I'm an iOS guy normally)

Comment: Menu items are like buttons. You can connect them to an action and a target in the XIB. Change the name of your print method and connect the menu item the first responder and this method.